# How to set background for uitextfield with uiimage

Tags: uiimageview, uitextfield

I want set background image for a `UITextField` with width:300 with `UIImageVIew` (22x43), but my `UIImageVIew` doesn't fit with my `UITextField`

So, how I can achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
myTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
```